# JaCoCo/EclEmma's Source highlighting function doesn't work when using PowerMock to Mock Constructor

Tags: highlight, powermock, jacoco

I used PowerMock to Mock Constructor.Afer launching the application,I thought all lines shoud be green.However,actually all lines are red.
I think Mocking Constructor results in this phenomenon.Beacause mocking others,like final classes, is OK.How to fix this problem?

```
//code:
public class People {
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}

public class Family {
    public String doEvent() {
        People p = new People();
        String str = p.sayHello();
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Family.class)
public class FamilyTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Family f = new Family();

        String str = "hello mock";
        People p = PowerMock.createMock(People.class);

        PowerMock.expectNew(People.class).andReturn(p);

        EasyMock.expect(p.sayHello()).andReturn(str);
        PowerMock.replay(p, People.class);

        String strActual = f.doEvent();

        Assert.assertEquals(str, strActual);
        PowerMock.verify(p, People.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to use `@PrepareForTest` unless you are mocking static methods inside that class.

I believe your issue is that when you prepare a class for test using Powermocks runner, it does something funky with the byte code, which EclEmma uses for line coverage. Since you are not mocking any static methods in your family class, try removing that from your `@PrepareForTest`.

Comment: I' mocking the constructor of People class,so It's necessary to use `@PrepareForTest` in the class-level.  you can see  [MockConstructor](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

Comment: Though I'm not mocking the family class,I think it's necessary based on the  [MockConstructor](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) documents.In this document,It said **The reason why we're not preparing File.class is that a new instance of the File is never created when doing  expectNew , PowerMock just intercepts the call to new from the class that does  new  and thus you need to prepare the PersistenceManager class in this example.** I'm mocking People class which is used in the family class,so I add `@PrepareForTest(Family.class)` in the class-level.